# How do I texture paint into a UV-unwrapped model?

Tags: texturing, uv, image, texture-painting

I was learning about UV-unwrapping the other day, and I have successfully unwrapped and applied a UV texture to my model. Now the problem is that, for some strange reason a certain part of my model remains un-textured.

To fix that, I was thinking about texture painting (with `stencil`) over that UV map on the untextured region, but I have to create a new image for that, and consequently lose my previous texture. Is there any other way, to paint that region?

*A detailed view of the model*:

[image]

**I want to apply a texture paint in the white region**

Comment: Can you see if maybe the area in question is actually assigned that material? Also, is that area also unwrapped in the same UV map?

Comment: Yea I had unwrapped the complete model, which also comprises of that un-textured area, nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

It was just silly of me to not think of this earlier. I just created a new material and assigned the un-textured area into it and then used the same texture map.

Comment: Which means you should have been able to then select the mesh that was white and assign it to the material you had.